# Why my WebService is not triggerd?

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, http-post

I use web-service to post some data but the web service is never triggered.

Here how I call web-service in the client:

```
    function saveData(year, month, someString) {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "../../Services/ReportDepartmentService.asmx/SaveXml",//?" + 'year=' + year + '&' + 'month=' + month,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "year": year, "month": month, "someString": someString }
        }).then(function success(response) {
            var success = true;
        }, function error(response) {
            var success = false;
        });
    }
```

Here is my web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void SaveXml(string year, string month, string someString)
    {
       //some logic
    }
```

But the web service SaveXml is never triggered.And in browser console I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: SaveXml Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Any idea why the trigger is not executed and why I get error above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate your web service like below. I have defined here to return format as "Json". If you require xml , you can change accordingly.

> As you are making ajax post call, you need to define that in your
>   service method (`ScriptMethod`).The class containing the Web / Script methods must have
>   the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in order to be callable
>   from ajax (as per the comment added by the `.asmx` code Template)

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://YourNameSpaceGoesHere/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ReportDepartmentService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string SaveXml(string year, string month, string someString)
    {
        string returnMessage = string.Empty;
        // Remaining code goes here.....
        // Assign Success/error message to your returnMessage. 
        return returnMessage;
    }
}
```

Change your Service class like below and let us know if it solves your problem

Comment: Welcome. Happy to Hear :)

Comment: Two questions: 1). Is the namespace entered in WebService is same as the URL in the client?(In the function saveData() if you see)?  2). UseHttpGet = false , why is this initialized as false?